# php json obj parsing in java

Tags: java, php, json, jsonexception

in the `php` file I am creating a `2d` dynamic array and while returning it am encoding using `json_encode`

```
 $ans=array('x'=>array(),'y'=>array(),'z'=>array());
    foreach ($result as &$y)
    { if(strpos($y,"x")){$ans['z'][]=substr(strstr($y,':'),12);}
      else if(strpos($y,"y")){$ans['y'][]=substr(strstr($y,':'),2);}
      else if(strpos($y,"z")){$ans['z'][]=substr(strstr($y,':'),2);} 
     }//$y is a very big string
     return json_encode($ans);
```

the output in browser shows as `{...}` I.E. jsonobject
but when in java I try to convert httpentity to `string(using entityutils.tostring)` and then make

```
jsonobject ja=new jsonobject(entityutils.tostring(entity));
```

shows following
`error : org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

why is it showing this?

edited :

```
List<NameValuePair> namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
         namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request",""+x)); 
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/webc.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if(entity!=null)
{String line=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject ja=new JSONObject(line);//showing error here
}
```

Comment: Because the text you're trying to supply to the `new jsonobject(...)` doesn't start with `{`, try to log each step of your code and it will become clear enough to find an error.

Comment: when seeing output in browser it does start with {

Comment: you might see `{` but it could be an html code of opening brace which will look the same `&#123;` http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm . Once more, trace your steps with log\System.out.println and ensure that you actually get json without trash

Comment: i get your point but when am not using json here and just seeing size of line it shows 48(whereas what am sending is quite big)